# imagemagick convert : tiff warnings / multiple output files created

Tags: java, imagemagick-convert

I am working on a java application that uses the ImageMagick convert utility to convert tiff to jpg.

Our workflow is to first do the tiff->jpg; create buffered img obj in order to get dimensions, then scale new dimensions, and run convert again to resize with the new dimensions and a few other options.

This works well the vast majority of the time, but in some cases I'm getting some tiff warnings, and while the img conversion is ultimately successful, convert creates a couple of interim images that are a problem. Here is what it looks like on the command line:

```
>convert testImg.tif test.jpg
convert.exe: Unknown field with tag 317 (0x13d) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/824.
convert.exe: Unknown field with tag 34391 (0x8657) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/824.
convert.exe: Unknown field with tag 34392 (0x8658) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/824.
convert.exe: testImg.tif: Null count for "Tag 34391" (type 1, writecount -3, pascount 1). `_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/562.
convert.exe: Unknown field with tag 317 (0x13d) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/824.
```

when starting with

```
testImg.tif
```

the outputs are

```
test-0.jpg
test-1.jpg
```

our workaround is to do the first conversion tif->gif then gif->jpg and that seems to fix it, but was wondering if anyone had come across this particular issue.

As an aside, we're using the convert util because we found JMagick to be very unreliable. If anyone has successfully used that, would be interested to hear any ideas about how to inforporate.

thanks!
bp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a java expert at all but have ran into the multiple images problem with imagemagick. This is due to tiff files containing layers. imagemagick will output every layer within the tiff. 
To get a specific layer and only 1...

> convert image.tif[0] image.jpg

Now this may affect quality. You may want to convert both and for each layer made, combine them 0-first 1 second.
From what I've found is that the layers after the first are less resolution though.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java, its the convert tool, i am on linux and i am also wondering why `convert 1.tif 1.png` creates multiple files. I think tiff's have multiple layers or so

Comment: H. The tiff files are 1 image made from multiple layers for some reason.  That is why I was saying when you convert it would be wise to combine them all. I suspect that there is a reason that the tiffs I have (from photoshop) contained layers of different quality. A guess is that it is the way browsers read and load the image possibly. Loading 1 layer at a time?... If that is the case the answer could be in the tiff documentations.

Comment: For `zsh` users: `[0]` gets interpreted by the shell. I did not manage to escape it in all cases -- if you run into issues, do the command in a `bash` shell.